# How to generate config file in an external bazel dependency

Tags: python, external, bazel

I'm new to bazel and trying to automatize updates in the [MapIt](http://mapit.poplus.org/docs/self-hosted/install/) database and code.

I named the root folder for my bazel project **bazel_mapit** where there is the WORKSPACE file and the BUILD file for this external dependency as follows.

WORSPACE:

```
new_git_repository(
    name            = "mapit_repo",
    remote          = "https://github.com/mysociety/mapit",
    tag             = "v2.0",
    build_file      = "mapit_repo.BUILD",
    init_submodules = 1,
```

)

mapit_reop.BUILD:

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

filegroup(
    name = "mapit_files",
    srcs = glob(
        [
            "**/*",
        ],
        exclude = [
            "**/LICENSE",
            "**/*.zip",
        ],
    ),
)
```

Now I want to generate the configuration file **conf/general.yml** inside the MapIt sources. The problem now is, when I add the following code to the mapit_repo.BUILD file, I getting errors that bazel can't find

> '@bazel_mapit//:general_yml.bzl'

mapit_repo.BUILD (extension):

```
load("@bazel_mapit//:general_yml.bzl", "general_yml")

general_yml(
    name = 'generate_general_yml',
    bzl_mapit_db_user = 'foo',
)

filegroup (
    name = 'mapit_general_yml',
    srcs = ['conf/general.yml'],
    data = ['conf/general.yml-example'],
)
```

How can I generate a config file in an external dependency?

Update:

This is the content of the working mapit_repo.BUILD file:

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

filegroup(
    name = "mapit_files",
    srcs = glob(
        [
            "**/*",
        ],
        exclude = [
            "**/LICENSE",
            "**/*.zip",
        ],
    ),
)

load("@//conf:general_yml.bzl", "general_yml")

general_yml(
  name = 'generate_general_yml',
  bzl_mapit_db_user = 'foo',
)

filegroup (
  name = 'mapit_general_yml',
  srcs = ['conf/general.yml'],
  data = ['@//conf:general.yml.tmpl'],
)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think all that needs to change is the `load()` mapit_repo.BUILD. That build file is going to be evaluated from within the external workspace, so to reference the bzl file in the main workspace, you can use `@//:general_yml.bzl`. (That is, the empty workspace name refers to the main workspace)

Comment: I changed mapit_repo.BUILD as you suggested and it fixed the problem. The only problem left is - the sources of the external repository is now under **bazel-bazel_mapit/external/mapit_repo** while the generated config file general.yml is located in **bazel-bazel_mapit/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/mapit_‌​repo/conf**. Why not the same folder?

Comment: Bazel doesn't put generated files into source folders for a few reasons. It would be annoying for source control because now you have to exclude the generated files. It might interfere with globbing, because the globs might start picking up the generated files. Those files might also start showing up in IDEs as sources. What issues are you running into?